# how we can add one by one row in table by using struts

Tags: struts2

I want to show data in tabular format when we click add button one by one keep adding in table . only use struts 2 not Ajax and Jquery.

```
home.jsp

  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:textfield label="Sainumber"
                                name="stockcreationbean.sainumber" /></td>

                        <td><table><tr><td><sx:datetimepicker
                                name="stockcreationbean.saidate" displayFormat="MM-dd-yy"
                                label="SaiDate" /></td></tr></table></td>

                        <td><s:textfield label="Challan"
                                name="stockcreationbean.challan"></s:textfield></td>

                        <td><table><tr><td><sx:datetimepicker name="stockcreationbean.challandate"
                                displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" label="ChallanDate"></sx:datetimepicker></td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:textfield label="BillNumber"
                                name="stockcreationbean.billnumber"></s:textfield></td>
                        <td><table><tr><td><sx:datetimepicker name="stockcreationbean.billdate"
                                displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" label="BillDate"></sx:datetimepicker></td></tr></table></td>

                        <td><s:textfield name="stockcreationbean.ponumber"
                                label="PoNumber"></s:textfield></td>
                        <td><table><tr><td><sx:datetimepicker name="stockcreationbean.podate"
                                displayFormat="MM-dd-yy" label="PoDate"></sx:datetimepicker></td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr><tr><td><s:textfield name="stockcreationbean.filenumber"
                                label="FileNumber"></s:textfield></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    <table>
    <s:iterator value="toparraylist"> 
                <tr> 
                <s:iterator value="tablelist">
                    <td><s:property value="saidate"/></td>
                </s:iterator>
                 </tr>
                 </s:iterator>  
        </table>
        <s:submit value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit(this.form)"></s:submit>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is action class that we can use for adding data in array list .One is local array list and other is global array list then call getData() method when we click add button then add local arraylist object to global arraylist object

```
    DisplayAction.java

     public class DisplayAction extends ActionSupport {
        ArrayList<Object> toparraylist = new ArrayList<Object>();
            public String execute()  {
                return "success";
            }
        public String getData() throws NamingException, Exception {

                ArrayList<Object> tablelist=new ArrayList<Object>();


                tablelist.add(stockcreationbean);
                toparraylist.add(tablelist);
                return "success";
            }

        public ArrayList<Object> getToparraylist() {
                return toparraylist;
            }
            public void setToparraylist(ArrayList<Object> toparraylist) {
                this.toparraylist = toparraylist;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Mack - could you try to format your post? It will help folks who are reading your questions.

Comment: To use jQuery Ajax with Struts2 you should use a corresponding plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@Mack Struts 2 is a server-side framework for java. If I decode your requirement it tells me that you want to update something on `table(at client)` and it gets updated on-by-one by using `struts 2(at server)`.

Ajax was fits your requirement perfectly and is the only solution for your requirement, as updating table is an asynchronous call to server.